# Can't format string to timestamp using mySQL?

Tags: mysql, date

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('2014-05-10 13:12:44','%Y-%m-%d %h:%m:%s'));
```

returns NULL. Am I missing something? I thought this would return a timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date format string should be `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'`.
`%m` means month, and `%h` means USA-style 0-12 hours, so 13 is no good.

Using STR_TO_DATE is almost as much fun as whistling into a modem, but not quite.  :-)

Comment: It works! However, when I change the string to a column from my table, it only formats the first one, and the rest return NULL.

Comment: huh? Are you storing your dates as strings in your table? If so, do they have the same sort of format as your sample in your question?

Comment: I figured it out. Just used timestamp() instead. I'll accept your answer when the timer is up.